# mysql count multiple row where

Tags: php, mysql

my question similar like this one [MySQL COUNT() multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625212/mysql-count-multiple-columns).

but for me , how do i count the mutliple row:

```
report table:

id     t_pro      t_price
1.    voucher    20.00
2.    pro        13.00
3.    pro 1x     13.00
4.    pro 2x       13.00
5.    voucher    20.00
6.    pro 1x       13.00 

$db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT t_pro WHERE t_pro LIKE 'pro%' AS pro_tan, SELECT t_pro WHERE t_pro LIKE 'voucher%' AS voucher) WHERE date=CURDATE()  ");
```

the result something like:

```
voucher : 2
pro tan : 4
```

Comment: why are you using a select within a select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT t_pro, COUNT(*) FROM report GROUP BY t_pro;
```

**NOTE:** this is if you want the count for each `t_pro` value. Otherwise, you'd need to modify the `GROUP BY` for custom `t_pro` value associations

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN t_pro LIKE 'voucher%' THEN 'voucher' WHEN t_pro LIKE 'pro%' THEN 'pro tan' END AS pro,
        COUNT(*)
FROM    mytable
WHERE   t_pro LIKE 't_pro%' OR t_pro LIKE 'voucher%'
GROUP BY
        pro
```

Comment: @Quassnoi: thanks. how do i echoing out the result? `echo pro tan = $r['pro']` ??

Comment: im not using any framework. its custom code on my own. how do i echoing the result like `voucher: 2, pro tan: 4`

Comment: @Quassnoi: sorry my bad :D.. its from $db = new Database() class

Answer (score 0):

```
select t_pro, count(1) from table group by t_pro;
```